# Counter withing a form output "#Form.Item(u)#"

Tags: forms, loops, coldfusion

I have a form that outputs different items in order the value of the items is coming out properly from the form (Value1,Value2,Value3) however when I try to do the same sort of counting method in my cfsets it does not work.

```html
<cfloop index="u" from="1" to="#arraylen( session.cart )#">
<cfset updateRow = session.cart[u]/>
<cfset session.cart[#u#].Ohm = "#Form.ohmicValue1#">
```

Essentially what I need the "1" to be is a variable (#u#) but how do I got about landing that within the #Form.OhmicValue[#u#]# I guess is the final question.

Thanks for the help.
Tom

Comment: You must have been using the wrong [search phrase](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bcoldfusion%5D+dynamic+variable+names) ;-)  FWIW, most all scopes (form, url, variables, etctera) are structures in CF. So you can use associative array notation to access any key dynamically , ie `theScopeName["theBaseName"& counter]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work

```
<cfloop index="u" from="1" to="#arraylen( session.cart )#">
  <cfset updateRow = session.cart[u]/>
  <cfset session.cart[u].Ohm = form['ohmicValue' & u]>
</cfloop>
```

Comment: Error Occurred While Processing Request
Element ohmicValue1 is undefined in a Java object of type class coldfusion.filter.FormScope.

Comment: Element ohmicValue1 is undefined in a Java object of type class coldfusion.filter.FormScope.

 
The error occurred in C:/Apache24/htdocs/krl/appendarray.cfm: line 23
21 : <cfset updateRow = session.cart[u]/>
22 : 
23 : <cfset session.cart[u].Ohm = form['ohmicValue' & u]>

Comment: I am sorry something in my browser had cached and I wouldn't work , however now it is working. Matt Thanks and Dan thanks for looking into it